# 'The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed.'

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

```
public ActionResult Index(FormModel form)
{
    using (DBModels db = new DBModels())

    {
        var clients = from c in db.Clients
                      select c;

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(form.SearchString))
        {
            clients = clients.Where(s => s.Full_Name.Contains(form.SearchString) || s.Class.Contains(form.SearchString)
            || s.Membership_Type.Contains(form.SearchString) || s.Membership_Type.Contains(form.SearchString) ||
            s.Notes.Contains(form.SearchString) || s.ClientID.Equals(form.SearchString));
        }
             if (form.IsChecked != null)
              {
                  clients = clients.Where(t => t.Paid == form.IsChecked);
              }
        return View(clients);

    }
}
```

Don't understand why this error is happening. I added a search box to search through the database. I also added a tick box to show the unpaid clients. When I change

```
return View(clients);
```

back to

```
return View(db.Client.ToList());
```

it works but is what i am trying to avoid as it shows all the list not the "clients" variable which shows the ones from the SearchString.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Your error occurs as the DBModel is already disposed when your view attempts to access the list. You can fix this a number of ways.  Either by changing the life time of the db variable... make it a member or you could change your controller and view to pass the required parameters to filter within your controller.  Without knowing what's going on in the view it's hard to provide an answer

Answer (score 2):

`clients` is an IQueryable. IQueryable doesn't enumerate it's values until the first iteration is requested. By that time, your DbContext has already been disposed, so the enumeration throws an exception.

To fix that, use something like

```cs
using (DBModels db = new DBModels())
{
    var clients = Enumerable.Empty<Client>();

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(form.SearchString))
    {
        clients = db.Clients.Where(s => s.Full_Name.Contains(form.SearchString) || s.Class.Contains(form.SearchString)
        || s.Membership_Type.Contains(form.SearchString) || s.Membership_Type.Contains(form.SearchString) ||
        s.Notes.Contains(form.SearchString) || s.ClientID.Equals(form.SearchString));
    }

    if (form.IsChecked != null)
    {
        clients = clients.Where(t => t.Paid == form.IsChecked);
    }

    return View(clients.ToList());
}
```

In theory, you should avoid the database call until the ToList() is called, but it's been awhile since I went that route. Instead, I'd recommend using [PredicateBuilder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx), from LinqKit, to build a query that will be completely run against the database, like so:

```cs
using (DBModels db = new DBModels())
{
    var predicate = PredicateBuilder.New<Client>(true);

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(form.SearchString))
    {
        predicate.And(s => s.Full_Name.Contains(form.SearchString) || s.Class.Contains(form.SearchString)
        || s.Membership_Type.Contains(form.SearchString) || s.Membership_Type.Contains(form.SearchString) ||
        s.Notes.Contains(form.SearchString) || s.ClientID.Equals(form.SearchString));
    }

    if (form.IsChecked != null)
    {
        predicate.And(t => t.Paid == form.IsChecked);
    }

    return View(db.Clients.Where(predicate).ToList());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

IQueryable type of data structures are for iteration purpose mainly, these won't don't yield value until ToList is used.
That's why your object is not evaluated after the dbcontext is disposed.